# Python - Detetives e Assassinos

Tags: python

Estou com dificuldade para entender o que esse exercício no link abaixo esta solicitando:

http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~mc102/labs/roteiro-lab06.html

O que eu entendi até agora, é que eu deveria construir um algoritmo para que, quando fosse fornecido os dados, esse algoritmo descobrisse quem é o assassino e quem é o detetive. É isso mesmo que o exercício esta propondo? Se sim, é muito sofisticado? Tenho conhecimento básico em Python, mas sei lidar bem com dicionários e instruções IF.

Se alguém puder dar um norte apenas de como começar já vai me ajudar muito.

Desde já muito obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve descobrir assassinos, vítima e detetives. O programa é relativamente simples, você só precisa se atentar com as regras de impressão.

Uma base:

```
• Receber a quantidade de casos. Exemplo: 1,2,3...100
• Verificar se a quantidade é >=1 e <=100
• Guardar os dados digitados em um dicionario
    -> <assassino> <vítima> <detetive>, com essa informação você pode criar um dicionário assim:
    relat = {'assassino':[], 
             'vitima':[],
             'detetive': []}
    nomes = set() # O meu conjunto vai guardar todos os nomes digitados ordenados e sem repetição, isso vai ajudar na impressão em ordem alfabética

    relat['assassino'].append('Ze')
    relat['vitima'].append('Xico')
    relat['detetive'].append({'Rafael':1}) # coloquei como dicionário para saber quantos casos cada detetive resolveu.
• Depois de criado seu dicionário com as entradas, só passar um for em nomes e recuperar a informação no dicionário, não esqueça de atender as regras.
```

Pesquise sobre o .split(), ele vai te ajudar com as entradas(tem nas dicas da tarefa).

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida só comentar ai.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rafael. Ajudou muito, vou começar a escrever o código.

Answer (score 1):

```
# coletando dados
N = input("Digite o numero de casos: ")
casos = []
if N < 1 or N > 100:
    print("Valor inválido na entrada.")
else:
    for i in range(N):
        caso = input("Digite assassino, vitima e detetive: ")
        caso = caso.split(' ')
        assassino, vitima, detetive = caso
        # caso = {"assassino":assassino,"vitima":vitima,"detetive":detetive} # dica do professor
        casos.append(caso)
```

Pra saber se a pessoa está viva, tem duas condições: não ter sido vítima e ser citada ou como assassina ou como detetive.
A lista 'casos' vai ter listas 'caso' como elementos, cujos elementos de índice 0, 1 e 2 serão, respectivamente, nomes do assassino, da vítima e do detetive.

Comment: Muito obrigado também Hog Dog, também me ajudou.